# FFMPeg exception setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: exception, ffmpeg

I have 175 mp4 files. When I process file from index 0 to index 65 (or 66), I get exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFFF
at wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(Native Method)
at com.jni.utils.Mp4ParserUsingFFMpeg.createThumbnail(Mp4ParserUsingFFMpeg.java:518)
at com.example.readmdtfile.activity.MainActivity$createMp4Async.createThumbnail(MainActivity.java:71)
at com.example.readmdtfile.activity.MainActivity$createMp4Async.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:55)
at com.example.readmdtfile.activity.MainActivity$createMp4Async.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

If I run process from index 65 (or nearby), processing file 65 is successful. But it still get exception sometimes
Here is code which i'm using:

```
public static Bitmap createThumbnail (String videoPath) {
    FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new  FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(videoPath); //file's path
        String key;
        String value;
        for (int i = 0; i < MetadataKey.METADATA_KEYS.length; i++) {
            key = MetadataKey.METADATA_KEYS[i];
            value = retriever.extractMetadata(key);
            if (value != null) {
                // metadata.add(new Metadata(key, value));
                Log.i(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
            }
        }

        bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime();

        if (bitmap != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Extracted frame");
            Bitmap b2 = retriever.getFrameAtTime(4000000,
                    FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
            if (b2 != null) {
                bitmap = b2;
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to extract frame");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        retriever.release();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever/issues/59

Please help me.

Comment: Did you set read permission in ur manifest.xml?

Answer (score 3):

The error is simple, an `IllegalArgumentException` means the video URI is invalid, if this occurs an exception is thrown. Verify the URI is valid before attempting to use it with `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is simple, an RuntimeException means the video URI is invalid. Verify the  valid Video URI with .mp4 format,  before attempting to use it with FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.

```
ImageView thumbnail1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.video1);
thumbnail1.setImageBitmap(retriveVideoFrameFromVideo("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"));

public Bitmap retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
    try {
        mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, new HashMap<String, String>());
        else
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
        //   mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
        bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(1, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } finally {
        if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null) {
            mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you just have to give setDataSource a String, save your path or url in a string like this:

```
String url;
mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
url = "http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2009.mp3";
mmr.setDataSource(url, new HashMap<String, String>());
```

or:

```
mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
string s="path"
mmr.setDataSource(path);
```