# Getting error while extracting video duration from a youtube url in android

Tags: java, android

```
public  long  getvideoDuration(String url){

    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(url));
    String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    long timeInmillisec = Long.parseLong( time );
    long duration = timeInmillisec / 1000;
    long hours = duration / 3600;
    long minutes = (duration - hours * 3600) / 60;
    long seconds = duration - (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60);

    return  seconds;
}
```

I am trying the above code for getting the duration of the video from a youtube url.....but getting an error at `retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(url))`

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:83)
```

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566480/mediametadataretriever-setdatasource-throws-illegalargumentexception

Comment: Still getting errors

Comment: StagefrightMetadataRetriever: Unable to instantiate an extractor for 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D31oblfZgN4'.                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException:setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000                          atandroid.media.MediaMetadataRetriever._setDataSource(Native Method)

Comment: Have you tried with `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever`?

Comment: i have tried it..also ..but it  seems to that...there  is no such class..

Comment: in my android studio

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18927304/5909385

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: getting the above error after using FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

Comment: Then check your URL and see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33204891/5909385

Comment: i am using hardcoded url i.e...which is a valid url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D31oblfZgN4

Comment: Did you add the permissions in the Manifest file?

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: yes iam using those permissions

Comment: see this for your reference: https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever/issues/22

Comment: Download zip file from this: https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever/releases/download/v1.0.9/prebuilt-aars-with-https.zip and add into your libs folder

Comment: For your reference: https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

Comment: getting same error.....

Comment: use any http: link and check it

Comment: i am looking for youtube video duration....and youtube automatically converts the url http to https

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36708456/5909385

Comment: tried already not working...